# what does XOR with non-binary numbers do?

Tags: bitwise-operators, xor

For example,

`0^1` will return `1` and

`1^1` will return `0`

This has it's obvious uses for flipping bits.

However, I have seen applications of XOR such as

`55^4` or `73^1`

I don't understand what the purpose of this is. Isn't it just checking that 55 and 73 are not equal to 4 and 1 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will convert both the numbers to binary number first and then apply bitwise XOR for all the bits

```
55 -> 110111
4  -> 000100
Xor-> 110011  ->which is equal to decimal 51.
```

Answer (score 0):

Many times if you have `a^b`, information in `a` is encoded in specific bits. You can XOR with a bit pattern to modify this information in useful ways. This is basically a **bitmask** (wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))).

For example, say you have some unsigned 32-bit integer that represents a user's permissions. Each bit corresponds to a particular permission. Say the 3rd least significant bit (3rd from the right) represents if the user is an admin or not. Then to toggle if the user is an admin, you can do something like this:

```
userRoles = userRoles ^ 0b100
```

or equivalently

```
userRoles = userRoles ^ 8
```